# HDCP compliance

Tags: macos, mac, display, hdmi, hdcp

When i connected mac to external five panasonic led display with Extron DA6 distribution amplifier, only four are connected but last dispaly flicker and then stop showing content.

I'm running on macos sierra version 10.12.1 processor 2 ghz, i7 processor, graphic intel iris pro 1536 mb.

How can I tell if this is a HDCP or edid issue?

Comment: Interesting setup. What Mac hardware and software versions are on play?

Comment: macos sierra version 10.12.1  processor 2 ghz, i7 processor, graphic intel iris pro 1536 mb

Comment: Just doing some preliminary research, the DA6 is analog - meaning HDCP and EDID, being digital, have nothing to do with this setup.